# Android - TextView textStyle is not changing

Tags: android, textview

I want to switch TextView style from Bold to Normal based on data I got.

I'm doing it like this:

```
reserveCount.setText("Reservations " + reservationCount);
if(reservationCount<20){
  Log.i("reserveCount", "typeface: NORMAL");
  reserveCount.setTypeface(reserveCount.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
} else {
  Log.i("reserveCount", "typeface: BOLD");
  reserveCount.setTypeface(reserveCount.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
}
```

But style is not changing at all (it stays bold all the time).

Comment: If you are using custom typeface, Better use different font for bold and normal .

Comment: have you checked the XML file of reserveCount is the font is BOLD or not..?

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        textView.setTextAppearance(resId);
    } else {
        textView.setTextAppearance(textView.getContext(), resId);
    }

Comment: Font is not set to bold in xml and I'm not using any custom fonts. Sometimes its working and sometimes not. Its some Android bug I assume. I will set font to BOLD and it changed to BOLD, but if I change it back to NORMAL, it stays BOLD. And sometimes if I change it to BOLD first time it stays NORMAL. So I dont understand whats going on.

Comment: It looks like both setTetxtAppearance and setTypeface are sometimes not working if set multiple times in a row (I load data 1: its bold, I load data 2: it stays bold). This seems to be bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to call `reserveCount.invalidate()` or `reserveCount.requestLayout()` at the end for forcing redraw `View`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like
`reserveCount.setText("Reservations " + reservationCount);`
`if(reservationCount<20){`
`Log.i("reserveCount", "typeface: NORMAL");`
`reserveCount.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));`
`} else {`
`Log.i("reserveCount", "typeface: BOLD");`
`reserveCount.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));`
`}`